# Empty search results return soft 404

Tags: search, 404-error

I have recently been notified by Google Webmaster tools that there has been an increase in soft 404 pages. This is due to no results being returned by pre-defined links to search queries that are intended to filter through custom post types that have predefined tags.

What would be the best way to prevent a 'soft 404', and satisfy Googles detection settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a web service such as [W3C Link Checker](https://validator.w3.org/checklink) to find out the broken links and fix it. Also based on what you described, if it a self-developed theme and caused due to search, make sure you will have a content template that handle the `none` content situation. You can check your theme's `search.php` and see how it handles the `none` content situation.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Creating a template for the content none situation is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: So problem solved? if not, share your search.php, will see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The [Cacheability](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cacheability/) WordPress plugin can remove soft 404s without any configuration.